# Maui Shell Uri Navigation, Multiplate pages on stack and backwards navigation

Tags: maui

I am developing a warehouse management application using Maui.
At the moment, I am using the GoToAsync method to navigate between pages, however, I have encountered a problem.

The structure of my pages:

Main menu with several buttons, select the first one:

1. Location ->
2. search location ->(after scanning the code)
   3.List of products on the location ->(after selecting the product)
   4.List with operations to perform (each one displays a different page) -> select the first one
   5.Move the product to another location
   etc.
   Depending on the button selected in point 4, a different number of pages can be put on the stack, for example, after selecting the operation in point 5, 3 or 4 or 5 more pages can be put on the stack.

This is how I register my pages:
      `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MenuPage), typeof(MenuPage)); Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ProductSearchPage), typeof(ProductSearchPage)); Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ProductListPage), typeof(ProductListPage)); Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ProductDetailsPage), typeof(ProductDetailsPage));`

So as you can see I don't create a hierarchy of Uri addresses e.g. Page1/Page2/Page3 because, pages like the code finder, or the product list can be accessed from different places in the program.

What I'm trying to do is go back to one of the pages set aside on the stack. In the example given above, I would like each operation selected in item 4 to, in effect, backtrack me to the list of products from level 3. I am unable to determine this using GoToAsync("../../../...") because I do not know how many pages have been set aside.

I would also like to mention that a page like a search engine or a list sends a message about the selected code or item has a list, and this is handled on one of the pages on the stack ( that is why I do not know how many pages I have to backtrack)

I tried GoToAsync(Page3) however it takes me to a new instance of that page, and additionally puts another page back on the stack.
Any ideas how I could approach such an issue?
Is Shell Uri navigation the right mechanism for this type of project?

Comment: If you wanna go back to a page already in your stack shouldn't you be calling `PopAsync` instead of `GotoAsync`

Comment: U mean Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync()? How do I choose a specific page on the stack that I want to go back to? That i can pass for example nameof(ProductListPage) ?

Comment: It may be easier to manipulate "navigation stack" by using [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0#manipulate-the-navigation-stack) instead of `Shell`: *"The Navigation property of a Page exposes a NavigationStack property from which the pages in the navigation stack can be obtained"*  Work backwards through stack, examining type of each page, to find the one you want. Remove the pages after it.